# Getting the Text Mask Library to work with Vue - error: does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, text-mask

I can get the vanilla javascript version going:

```js
var maskedInputController = vanillaTextMask.maskInput({
    inputElement: document.querySelector('.myInput'),
    mask: [/\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/],
});
```

```html
<input placeholder="__/__/____" class="myInput"></input>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanilla-text-mask@5.1.1/dist/vanillaTextMask.min.js"></script>
```

But I have no idea how to get the vue version going. It says that it does not provide an export named 'default'.

Github here: https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask

Vue instructions here: https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/vue

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    MaskedInput
  },
  data() {
    return {
      phone: '',
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label>Phone Number</label>
  <masked-input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" v-model="phone" :mask="['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]" :guide="false" placeholderChar="#">
  </masked-input>
</div>

<script type="module">
  import MaskedInput from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-text-mask@6.1.2/dist/vueTextMask.min.js';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the github Issues:

```js
const MaskedInput = window.vueTextMask.default
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { MaskedInput },
    data: {
        date: '',
        mask: [/\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-text-mask@6.1.2/dist/vueTextMask.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    Date:
    <masked-input v-model="date" :mask="mask" placeholder="__/__/____"></masked-input>
</div>
```